# Import multiple files in Hive with differents structures

Tags: python, csv, hadoop, hive

I have two problems, please help me to solve them.

**Problem 1:** File structure
I have 3 files with these columns:

- log_in.csv (request_id, date_in, origin)
- log_out.csv (request_id, date_out, destination)
- request.csv (request_id, date_request, user)

Each file is written in differents moments, so the "date" is not the same. The request_id is the same in all files, if the request is complete.

Exemple:

*log_out.csv*

```
request_id |       date_out      |  destination
    1      | 2015-11-13 01:02:02 | 192.168.0.7
    3      | 2015-11-13 05:01:05 | 192.168.0.5
    4      | 2015-11-13 03:09:02 | 192.168.0.10
```

*log_in.csv*

```
request_id |       date_in       |    origin
    1      | 2015-11-13 01:02:03 | 192.168.0.10
    2      | 2015-11-13 02:03:04 | 192.168.0.9
    4      | 2015-11-13 03:09:02 | 192.168.0.3
```

*request.csv*

```
request_id |       date_in       |  user
    1      | 2015-11-13 01:02:01 | user1
    2      | 2015-11-13 02:03:01 | user2
    3      | 2015-11-13 02:03:01 | user1
    4      | 2015-11-13 03:09:01 | user3
```

What is the better way to store these files?

**Problem 2:** Directory

How can I properly struct my diretory and load the files if they have the same name by day in HDFS?

*Exemple as is:*

```
LOGS / 20151113 / log_out.csv
LOGS / 20151113 / log_in.csv
LOGS / 20151113 / request.csv
LOGS / 20151114 / log_out.csv
LOGS / 20151114 / log_in.csv
LOGS / 20151114 / request.csv
.
.
.
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you looking to store the data in 3 tables? or trying to load the data in hdfs in the best way possible?
regarding directory structure: Are you looking to save the files under date directory. If yes, That possible!

Comment: @Anil Could it be 3 tables, but if you can store in HDFS in other structure it will serve as well to this situation

Comment: @Anil I am trying to figure out the best way to store and also load these files, which structure should I use in HDFS and the best way to access the data later.  About the file structure, not necessary under date directory (It probably would envolve partition and I dont know if it is the better way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Otavio R. Rossi: You can create 3 (external) tables, login, logout and request if the data is already in hdfs

Something like,

```
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE login(
     request_id INT,
     date_out TIMESTAMP,
     destination STRING
     )
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
    STORED AS TEXTFILE;
    LOAD  DATA  INPATH  'hdfs location'
```

Now these tables can be partitioned by date or year/month/day depending up on your usecse.

Also, if you are looking for correlation, you can consider loading all the data in to one table by joining all the 3 tables on request_id. hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
However, in this case that you mentioned (loading all the data in one table), how can I load data from 3 files by joining them in a single table,  if each file has different number of columns? Would that be possible? What if the number of columns would be 10 (lot of null inside the table)?

Comment: yes @OtavioR.Rossi: Thats how aggregation works ;)
Join the 3 tables on a key (request_id) here